# How can I record values from another website and put it in a database to be used?

Tags: javascript, analysis

For example, how would I go about designing a program that, upon the user inputting their location, will display a temperature listed on another website, which I can then manipulate using JavaScript.

Comment: You need to add more information. What website? What database? If you want to save something in database then you probably have some server. Then what server technology do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

If I understand correctly you want to query a web service to get the temperature for a given location.  Here is a sample using jinqJs

```
var weatherSvc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Huntington,NY';

var result = jinqJs()
                    .from(weatherSvc)
                    .select(function(row){ return row.main.temp;});
```

[See Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/gdrwjqL1/3/)

Comment: Thanks @NYTom for your helpful answer! Does the method you propose involving JinqJs require an in depth understanding of Javascript or the JinqJs framework? Or is it as simple as inputting a few lines of code as you showed above?

Comment: Its very simple the API. See examples at http://jinqjs.com/Examples or the API at http://jinqjs.com/Help. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to allow users to search a location, and then have jinqJS return values based on that? I was thinking possibly using something like this:

var location = input("What is your location?");
var weatherSvc = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location ;
var result = jinqJs()
        .from(weatherSvc)
        .select(function(row){return row.main.temp;});

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format my code nicely on here!

Comment: Thanks so much @NYTom, can't tell you enough how much I appreciate it! It'll take me a bit of time to understand your code, but I'll be back with more questions soon!

Comment: Hey @NYTom, any idea how to tackle the challenges in the comment below?

Comment: Your fiddle was missing the link to jinqJs. I added it and it runs now. http://jsfiddle.net/tford/p0dmjpto/4/

Comment: Ah,  thanks! It still only shows the temperature when I it "Get temp". Any idea why? I tried a little fix but it still doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ajurgens/p0dmjpto/5/

Comment: Here is a working copy: http://jsfiddle.net/tford/p0dmjpto/6/  The issue was with the self closing span tags.